# Regex substring with delimiter

Tags: regex

I have the following text (could be infinite number of delimited pairs):

```
zz=yy /* animal=cat,AA=bb, qqq=dd */ yyy=ttt
```

I would like to use regex to get all matches of the delimited strings within the code comment:

```
1. animal=cat
2. AA=bb
3. qqq=dd
```

but not: zz=yy or yyy=ttt

**Update:**
I have tested the suggested patterns (all good, I learnt a lot, thanks). I continued to experiment and found the following pattern:

```
(?:\/\*\s*|\G\s*,\s*)(?:(\w+)=(\w+)(?:\s*\*\/)?)
```

Which takes less steps and also handles multiline. Do you see any problem with this solution?

https://regex101.com/r/YfC4dS/1/

Comment: An issue with your updated regex is that it will match pairs outside of `/* */`s if the pair occurs right after a `,`: https://regex101.com/r/YfC4dS/2

Comment: Another issue is that it requires everything inside the `/* */`s to be in that particular key-value format, otherwise it'll break: https://regex101.com/r/YfC4dS/3

Comment: Good points. I am less concerned with the second point.
Any suggestion how to fix the first point and force the pairs to be within the comment?

Comment: You can use the same technique as in my answer, negative lookahead for the beginning of the string when you match `\G`, and don't (even optionally) match `*/`, so that the next `\G` will fail. You can also move both trailing `\s*`s inside the first group's alternations outside, to combine them: https://regex101.com/r/YfC4dS/4

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. I made a slight modification also to answer the 'value with space and commas': https://regex101.com/r/YfC4dS/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is

```
(\b\w+)=(\w+\b)(?=(?:(?!\/\*).)*\*\/)
```

In plain language, what that means is: after the `=` pair, lookahead for (characters that don't include the `/*` substring), followed by `*/`.

https://regex101.com/r/Dvx99F/1

An alternative that takes fewer steps, matching from the beginning of the `/*`s instead:

```
(?:\/\*|\G(?!^))(?:(?!\*\/|\/\*).)*?(\b\w+)=(\w+\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Dvx99F/2

Comment: OP didn't note that his input could include newlines, but if so, the tweak is quite simple, just use `s` modifier (or, if not available, `[\s\S]`)

Answer (score 1):

If your engine supports `\G`, you may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|/\*)
(?:(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])+?)
(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\w+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/alndXT/1/).

---

Explained:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|/\*)             # match /* or at the end of the last match
(?:(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])+?)      # fast-forward
(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\w+)  # key/value pair
```